# How to record the exact time of the first and last movie frame captured with AVCaptureSession?

Tags: avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapture, avcapturemoviefileoutput

I'm using `AVCaptureSession` to capture a video into a movie file. I want to get the exact timestamp of the first and last frame of the movie. How do I do this?

In `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate`, the method `captureOutput(_:didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:fromConnections:)` is called when movie recording starts, but it is too inaccurate for my purposes, as is the callback for when recording ends. I need the exact timestamp of the frame.

In `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`, the method `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:` gets called per frame, and can be used to access explicit timestamp information for the frame, so that should be plenty accurate.

Unfortunately, it seems you cannot configure a capture session to simultaneously record to a video file and to provide raw sample data, so I cannot use this to get frame timestamps while also capturing to a file.

Or is there some way to use them both at once? Or am I missing another piece of API I could use?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I raised a Developer Technical Support ticket with Apple regarding this issue, in order to get a final answer.

The Apple engineer confirmed there is no way to access both pieces of API simultaneously. So if you want exact timestamps and record a video file, then you need to conform to `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` and build the file yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, it seems you cannot configure a capture session to
> simultaneously record to a video file and to provide raw sample data,
> so I cannot use this to get frame timestamps while also capturing to a
> file.

With regards to this statement - it is indeed possible to create a capture session that has both a AVCaptureMovieFileOutput and a AVCaptureVideoDataOutput.  However, the timing information provided with the Data Output CMSampleBuffers will not align with the timing information recorded into the movie file (there is now way to know the exact timing of frame zero for one relative to the other).  So, the solution would be to utilize AVAssetWriter as mentioned in another answer.

Here is an excerpt from my code showing parallel configuration.

```
    movieFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
    
    if session.canAddOutput(movieFileOutput!) {
        session.addOutput(movieFileOutput!)
    }
    
    dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    
    dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: sampleBufferQueue)
    dataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
    if session.canAddOutput(dataOutput) {
        session.addOutput(dataOutput)
    }
```